# Numpy array not changing the array itself

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Im not sure if im missing something out because i'm new to Python, but according to a few threads and docs that I've read like [this one](https://www.w3resource.com/numpy/manipulation/insert.php), from what i understand the numpy should change the array since im passing it by parameter. Thats not what is occurring in my code though.

```
class Graph(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.arr = self.createArray()


def insertVertice(self):
    ##SHAPE = (1,1) - (2,2)
    np.insert(self.arr, 0, 0, axis=1)
```

if I let the code like this and print "arr", the bidimensional array stays the same [[0 0]
[0 0]] but if I do it like:

```
self.arr = np.insert(self.arr, 0, 0, axis=1)
```

It changes...[[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]]

Does anyone have a clue on what am I missing here?

Comment: the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) clearly states that `Note that insert does not occur in-place: a new array is returned.`

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I've read that, I just wasn't really feeling secure by make an attribution to the same value that I'm passing by parameter.

Comment: That's a very common usage, you should get use to it. Here is a link to the [`return` statement best practices](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#using-the-python-return-statement-best-practices), maybe you'll find more information and learn what was missing here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [doc](https://www.w3resource.com/numpy/manipulation/insert.php) you linked, it is clearly specified :

> Return value:
> out [ndarray] A copy of arr with values inserted. Note that insert does not occur in-place: a new array is returned. If axis is None, out is a flattened array.

That means you have to use the return value as you are doing in the second example, the operation is not on the input array directly.